# webpage flickers on UIWebview in iPad

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, flicker

I have a single view appication where I am trying to load jQuery Demos from this site:

> http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/ on a UIWebView.
>   But when I click on a component from the demo, I can see a white screen flickers for few milli seconds and only it happens in portrait mode (for landscape it does not appear so). I have spent almost an entire day digging into this, yet no success. I have already posted this query to jQuery mobile forum but have not got any reply yet.

I'm not sure whether it's a bug in UIWebView or in jQuery site.

any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: I see this when loading just regular HTML into the UIWebView. So I doubt it's jQuery specific.

Comment: @dnstevenson: thanks for your input. Finally found out the issue and fixed it too. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue, it's something with CSS for webkit. For this you need to call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` on your UIWebview object and pass the parameter which is something like this:

[yourwebviewObject stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$(document).ready(function(){"
     "$('head').append('.ui-page {"
     "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;"
     "}')"
     "});"];

Hope it will help out there someone.